# degree of polynomial in Gröbner basis

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $f(x, y) =  \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} a_{m,n} x^m y^n$ and $g(x, y) =  \sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_{m,n} x^m y^n$. Computing the Gröbner basis, we get an univariate polynomial $h_1(x)$ and a bivariate polynomial $h_2(x, y)$. What is the degree of $h_1(x)$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That depends on the chosen monomial order, and on $f$ and $g$. 
A lower bound is the degree of the zero polynomial.

Comment: I guess the monomial order is y > x (since (s)he eliminates y), so h1 divides the resultant of f,g w.r.t. y. 

Answer (score 3):

In general, there is the following result on upper bounds for the degree of elements in the (reduced) Groebner basis: Let $G$ be a reduced Groebner basis of an ideal $I=\langle f_1,\ldots, f_r\rangle $. Let $d$ be the maximal degree (with respect to some monomial order) of $deg(f_1),\ldots ,deg(f_r)$. Let $n$ be the dimension of the ring (the number of variables). Then we have
$$
max \lbrace deg(g) \mid g\in G \rbrace \le 2\left(\frac{d^2}{2}+d\right)^{2^{n-1}}. 
$$
The result is due to Thomas W. Dubé  (1990).

Of course, for the equations $f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0$ we may just take the resultant $h_1(x)=res(f(y)(x),g(y)(x))$ with respect to $x$. No Groebner basis is needed then, and the degree can be estimated easily.